# Как конвертировать изображение в строчные байты используя base64?

Tags: python-3.x, base64

Открываю файл и использую следующее

```
encoded_photo = base64.b64encode(imagefile.read())
```

На выходе байты

```
b'/9j/4QG1RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwEQAAIAAAAaAAAAYgEAAAQAAAABAAADwAEBAAQAAAABAAAFAAEyAAIAAAAUAAAAfAESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAlwEPAAIAAAAHAAAAkAAAAABBbmRyb2lkIFNESyBidWl ......
```

Как мне положить в постман для проверки тоже самое только в формате строки таким образом

```
'/9j/4QG1RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwEQAAIAAAAaAAAAYgEAAAQAAAABAAADwAEBAAQAAAABAAAFAAEyAAIAAAAUAAAAfAESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAlwEPAAIAAAAHAAAAkAAAAABBbmRyb2lkIFNESyBidWl ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простое действие

```py
its_bytes = b'/9j/4QG1RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwEQAAIAAAAaAAAAYgEAAAQAAAABAAADwAEBAAQAAAABAAAFAAEyAAIAAAAUAAAAfAESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAlwEPAAIAAAAHAAAAkAAAAABBbmRyb2lkIFNESyBidWl'

its_string = its_bytes.decode("utf-8")
print(its_string)

# out
# '/9j/4QG1RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwEQAAIAAAAaAAAAYgEAAAQAAAABAAADwAEBAAQAAAABAAAFAAEyAAIAAAAUAAAAfAESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAlwEPAAIAAAAHAAAAkAAAAABBbmRyb2lkIFNESyBidWl'
```

Все в границах `built-in` типов данных. [Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) по данному вопросу

Метод `bytes.decode()` возвращает строку расшифрованную из заданной последовательности байт. То есть на выходе, переменная `its_string` будет иметь строковой тип данных, что и требуется.

Проверим

```py
>>> print(type(its_string))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, ответ, указав что и для чего и почему делает этот код.

Comment: Спасибо, сам тоже нашел это.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов на здоровье=)